# How to change rubocop's default settings?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Is it possible to change rubocop's default settings? I would like something along the lines of `~/.rubocop_default.yml`, but I didn't find anything like this in documentation. But it must be possible, right? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create `.rubocop.yml` file in either in your home directory or in some project directory and override settings you want. See the [official manual](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.2/configuration.html#config-file-locations) for more information.

Comment: but I would have to do this for every single project, correct?

Comment: @Palladin, from docs: `The file can be placed either in your home directory or in some project directory.`

Comment: Link mentioned in the answer does not work anymore. Here is the link that works at the time of writing: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.2/configuration.html